# Is there a way to suppress warning "Commented out code (n lines)" in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I know, its not a good practice, but is there a way in Android Studio to suppress warning "`Commented out code (n lines)`"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `noinspection` to the first line of the comment works for me:

```
/* noinspection
 multiline 
 comment
 goes
 here
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this way, this works for me in both Android Studio and Intellij Idea:

```
/*/ first line
  second line 
  ...
  n line */
```